# xset: unable to open display ""

Tags: xorg, systemd

I have a keyboard that has backlights that don't startup by default when I use ubuntu and so I have to manually execute a script every time after startup to enable the backlights..

I wanted to automate this so that the script was run automatically and so I created a systemd service unit to take care of it.

The problem is that the service unit does not run even when started from the terminal

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start keyboard-lights.service
```

I have created a `.service` file inside of `/etc/systemd/system/`

```
[Unit]
Description=Startup script for keyboard backlights

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/keyboard-lights.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script for enabling the keyboard lights is in `/usr/local/bin/keyboard-lights.sh`

I have made the script executable using

```
chmod 744 /usr/local/bin/keyboard-lights.sh
```

What am I missing from my `.service` file that is causing the script to not be run?

#### log from running `journalctl -xe`

```
Oct 23 22:09:13 user keyboard-lights.sh[3479]: running keyboard-lights script
Oct 23 22:09:13 user keyboard-lights.sh[3479]: xset:  unable to open display ""
Oct 23 22:09:13 user systemd[1]: keyboard-lights.service: Main process exited, code=exite
Oct 23 22:09:13 user systemd[1]: keyboard-lights.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 23 22:09:13 user systemd[1]: keyboard-lights.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

#### log from running `ls -lZ`

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root ? 199 Oct 23 22:00 /etc/systemd/system/keyboard-lights.service
```

### Additional edit:

this is the `keyboard-lights.sh` script and it works when I run this on its own.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "running keyboard-lights script"
if [ -f /tmp/keyboard_light ]; then
xset -led 3 && rm /tmp/keyboard_light
else
xset led 3 && touch /tmp/keyboard_light
fi
```

## EDIT:

I changed the title of the post to reflect what I believe is the issue causing the problem.

I have tried searching the web and have not found a solution to `xset:  unable to open display ""`

I did try adding `export DISPLAY=:0` to my shell script but this did not fix the issue.

I altered my service file to just run the command for turning the keyboard lights on by changing the `ExecStart` line to

```sh
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "xset led 3"
```

but the error `xset:  unable to open display ""` still persists.

Why is it that the command will run in my terminal fine (turning the keyboard lights on) but will not run without error in my service file when I start it?

Comment: `chmod 744` enables execution only for file owner! Can you verify the file owner (output of `ls -l /usr/local/bin/keyboard-lights.sh`)?

Comment: -rwxr--r-- 1 root root 172 Oct 23 21:47 /usr/local/bin/keyboard-lights.sh

Comment: `Oct 23 22:09:13 user systemd[1]: keyboard-lights.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE`

    `Oct 23 22:09:13 user systemd[1]: keyboard-lights.service: Unit entered failed state.`

    `Oct 23 22:09:13 user systemd[1]: keyboard-lights.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.`

keyboard-lights.sh runs manually yes but keyboard-lights.service does not

Comment: Sorry it still doesn't run successfully after making those changes

Comment: I am confident the issue surrounds the log `xset:  unable to open display ""`

Comment: If that's the case you can use `Environment=DISPLAY=:0` in your file.

Comment: @Danoram `Type=oneshot` is a `[Service]` directive btw.

Comment: I suggest you write all these things into an answer so things are more clear

Comment: @Danoram I would but first we need some troubleshooting before I or someone else can provide an answer.

Comment: I think it more useful to have an answer that can be edited than runaway comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67502/discussion-between-val0x00ff-and-danoram).

Comment: Can you try running `xhost +` using terminal, restart the service and see if it solved the problem?

Comment: Sorry but it has been two years. I don't have much interest in revisiting this anymore. The original setup I had is long gone :(